# Adding an aidl file to Android.mk

Tags: android, aidl

I'm adding an aidl file to my project, to cope with a "ClassNotFound" exception I'm getting when I call intent.getIntExtra (..), (because of another parcelable object in the same intent extras)

I added the following .aidl file (SomeInfo.aidl)

```
package com.someapp;
parcelable SomeInfo;
```

I added to Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES := src/com/someapp/SomeInfo.aidl
```

But when I'm building the project, I see no difference.
Actually, if I add to my code

```
import com.someapp.SomInfo;
```

The compiler can't find it...

Please help

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to add it to LOCAL_SRC_FILES as well, like:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src) src/com/someapp/SomeInfo.aidl
LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES := src/com/someapp/SomeInfo.aidl
```

Or you can use predefined functions like:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src) $(call all-Iaidl-files-under, src)
LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES := $(call all-Iaidl-files-under, src)
```

Let me add more details. Actually base_rules.mk is the one defining rules of handling aidl files: http://androidxref.com/4.4.3_r1.1/xref/build/core/base_rules.mk#178. It'll pick up all files with aidl extension automatically like this:

```
aidl_sources := $(filter %.aidl,$(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
```

And the LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES list you're adding your aidl files into, is actually defined to be -I* param of AIDL compiler:

```
$(aidl_java_sources): PRIVATE_AIDL_FLAGS := -b $(addprefix -p,$(aidl_preprocess_import)) -I$(LOCAL_PATH) -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/src $(addprefix -I,$(LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES))
```

Comment: What if my *.aidl file define in library, is not in current local path, just like ../LibraryProject/aidl, how to fix?

Comment: I've never heard of an `Android.mk` and `base_rules.mk`... but I want to have the `.aidl` files of my parcelable Objects inside of my library module and not in the client app... Can you maybe add a full example of the files and where I have to add them to make it work? Do I have to register them anywhere?

Comment: @codezjx.
This 'all-Iaidl-files-under' function returned with path relative to $(LOCAL_PATH). You can specify library path directly from your root project. That is, LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES := LibraryProject/aidl